# Element got undefined after append on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to do on page Edit Script for Text and

My Code is

**JQUERY ::**

```
$( "#box" ).click(function() {   
    var oldText = $( "#box" ).text();
    $( "#box" ).html('<textarea id="vbox">'+oldText+'</textarea>');
    $(this).attr("id","nbox");
});

$( "#savetxt" ).click(function() {
    alert($('vbox').val());
    $( "#nbox" ).html($('vbox').val());
    $("#nbox").attr("id","box");
});
```

**HTML ::**

```
<div id="box">
    sd,afmg dasfgds gdfs ,gd, gmfdsvdgfbhdsfg/dfs
    sdfgdfs
    gdfsgkdfg

</div>
<input id="savetxt" type="button" value="Save" />
```

This JSFiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/BQGPA/12/ check it

When I try to get text from textearea it returns `undefined`

Comment: You forgot to put a hex "#" in front of the vbox. Instead of $('vbox'), it should be $('#vbox')

Comment: yes, thanks , i update in Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BQGPA/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( document ).on('click', "#savetxt", function() {
    alert($('#vbox').val());
    $( "#nbox" ).html($('#vbox').val());
    $("#nbox").attr("id","box");
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/BQGPA/13/)

And so that you do not lose your styling change:

```
var oldText = $( "#box" ).text();
```

To:

```
var oldText = $( "#box" ).html();
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/BQGPA/16/)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're after:

```
function edit() {
    $(this).off('click');
    var oldText = $("#box").html();
    $("#box").html('<textarea id="vbox">' + oldText + '</textarea> </br><input id="savetxt" type="button" value="Save" />');
}
$("#box").click(edit);
$(document).on('click', "#savetxt", function () {
    $("#box").html($('#vbox').val());
    $("#box").click(edit);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P44Qt/)**

One error was the missing `#` in `$('vbox').val()`, the other was that you need to use event delegation on dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#box").click(function () {   
    var oldText = $( "#box").text();
    $( "#box" ).html('<textarea id="vbox">' + oldText + '</textarea></br><input id="savetxt" type="button" value="Save" />');
    $(this).attr("id", "nbox");
    $("#savetxt").on("click", function () {
        alert($('#vbox').val());
        $("#nbox").html($('vbox').val());
        $("#nbox").attr("id", "box");
    });
});
```

You can't assign a click event to an element that doesn't exist. You may use delegation for this or simply add the click event after you dynamically create the element.